# Speed up ifdown / ifup

Tags: debian, networking

I'm developing a JavaScript application which calls some bash scripts to change network settings. Restarting network interface takes too long (like 20 sec or more) on some networks:

```
ifdown eth0; ifup eth0
```

I wonder whether I need to always restart interface when I edit `/etc/network/interfaces` (change IP, netmask, gateway, set DHCP), `/etc/resolv.conf` (changes DNS), `/etc/apt/apt.conf` (proxy for apt).

Also I think about restarting DHCP client in some situations (but not sure when this would be sufficient). Could you please shed light on this issue.

Comment: Restarting an interface shouldn't take anywhere near this long. What takes so long? Are you getting an IP address through DHCP? What else are you doing on connection establishment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most options can be changed dynamically using tools like `ifconfig`, `route`, `ip`, `ndd`, etc. so you might consider to use a different strategy: change options dynamically using other tools and save the options to the configuration file to be persistent.

Changes to `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/apt/apt.conf` are immediately in effect.